# Can't login to wordpress after changed url

Tags: wordpress

I just made a website http://webmasteroffers.com, I installed it on a Nginx web server, the default install url is http (without www), then I loged in to WP Dashboard and changed the site url to http://www.webmasteroffers.com, after that I unable to login to my website, there is not error display when I type username and password and enter. It seems the cookie problems. I tried to change the url in database by login to phpmyadmin but even after changed url to http:// I still can't login to the site.
Overall, I can't login to my site now.

Do you known how to fix this issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the server log. Can you post the logs so that we can analyse better.

BR